# *ngFor - Loop iteration is not happening. Only one element of the object is displaying instead of all (in Angular 12)

Tags: angular

My array of objects is not looping in the UI. Only one element I can able to get. What am I doing wrong? Please help to rectify this.

my **component.html** file as follows:

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let regionList of regionLists; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
  <div class="card-body">
    {{ regionList.output.list[i].region }}
  </div>
</div>
```

**my componnent.ts** - I have given two objects for demo purposes where I need to display regions i.e ouput should have 2 cards where i'm getting only one

```
import { query } from '@angular/animations';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'apiDemoApp';
  query:string;
  regionLists:any[];

  
constructor(){
  this.query="ramlal";
  this.regionLists=[{
    "transactionId":"abc",
    "output":{
       "list":[
          {
             "region":"Africa",
             "apis":[
                {
                   "name":"Address Validation",
                   "status":"Operational",
                   "time":"98%",
                   "sec":"160ms"
                },
                {
                  "name":"Address Validation",
                  "status":"Operational",
                  "time":"98%",
                  "sec":"160ms"
               }, {
                "name":"Address Validation",
                "status":"Operational",
                "time":"98%",
                "sec":"160ms"
             },

                {
                   "apiName":"Locations",
                   "status":"Operational",
                   "upTime":"98%",
                   "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                },
                {
                   "apiName":"Pickup",
                   "status":"Operational",
                   "upTime":"98%",
                   "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                },
                {
                   "apiName":"Track",
                   "status":"Operational",
                   "upTime":"98%",
                   "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                },
                {
                   "apiName":"Rate",
                   "rateSubApis":[
                      {
                         "apiName":"Rate Express",
                         "status":"Operational",
                         "upTime":"98%",
                         "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                      },
                      {
                         "apiName":"Rate Freight",
                         "status":"Operational",
                         "upTime":"98%",
                         "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                      },
                      {
                         "apiName":"Rate Ground",
                         "status":"Operational",
                         "upTime":"98%",
                         "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                      },
                      {
                         "apiName":"Rate SmartPost",
                         "status":"Operational",
                         "upTime":"98%",
                         "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "apiName":"Ship",
                   "shipSubApis":[
                      {
                         "apiName":"Ship Express",
                         "status":"Operational",
                         "upTime":"98%",
                         "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                      },
                      {
                         "apiName":"Ship Freight",
                         "status":"Operational",
                         "upTime":"98%",
                         "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                      },
                      {
                         "apiName":"Ship Ground",
                         "status":"Operational",
                         "upTime":"98%",
                         "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                      },
                      {
                         "apiName":"Ship SmartPost",
                         "status":"Operational",
                         "upTime":"98%",
                         "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                      }
                   ]
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "region":"Americas and Caribbean",
             "apis":[
                {
                   "apiName":"Address Validation",
                   "status":"Operational",
                   "upTime":"98%",
                   "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                },
                {
                   "apiName":"Locations",
                   "status":"Operational",
                   "upTime":"98%",
                   "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                },
                {
                   "apiName":"Pickup",
                   "status":"Operational",
                   "upTime":"98%",
                   "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                },
                {
                   "apiName":"Track",
                   "status":"Operational",
                   "upTime":"98%",
                   "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                },
                {
                   "apiName":"Rate",
                   "rateSubApis":[
                      {
                         "apiName":"Rate Express",
                         "status":"Operational",
                         "upTime":"98%",
                         "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                      },
                      {
                         "apiName":"Rate Freight",
                         "status":"Operational",
                         "upTime":"98%",
                         "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                      },
                      {
                         "apiName":"Rate Ground",
                         "status":"Operational",
                         "upTime":"98%",
                         "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                      },
                      {
                         "apiName":"Rate SmartPost",
                         "status":"Operational",
                         "upTime":"98%",
                         "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "apiName":"Ship",
                   "shipSubApis":[
                      {
                         "apiName":"Ship Express",
                         "status":"Operational",
                         "upTime":"98%",
                         "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                      },
                      {
                         "apiName":"Ship Freight",
                         "status":"Operational",
                         "upTime":"98%",
                         "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                      },
                      {
                         "apiName":"Ship Ground",
                         "status":"Operational",
                         "upTime":"98%",
                         "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                      },
                      {
                         "apiName":"Ship SmartPost",
                         "status":"Operational",
                         "upTime":"98%",
                         "avgResponseTime":"160ms"
                      }
                   ]
                }
             ]
          },
        
       ],
       "userRegion":"Indian Sub-Continent",
       "Country":"India"
    }
 }]
}
}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Expected output: Two cards as per objects in array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have the second loop for the lists.

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let regionList of regionLists; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
  <div class="card-body">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let listItem of regionList.output.list">
      {{ listItem.region }}
   </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two dimensional array but you have used one `ngFor`, so you need nested `ngFor` like this:

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let regionList of regionLists; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div *ngFor="let list of regionList.output.list">
            {{ list.region }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me as taken helpful answers given. Thanks

```
    <div  *ngFor="let regionList of regionLists; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
      <div class="card" *ngFor="let listItem of regionList.output.list">
        <div class="card-body">
         <ng-container >
            {{ listItem.region }}
         </ng-container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are adding now an extra outer div which were not necessary if you used ng-container for the loop like in my answer. In the version you provided here you could completely omit ng-container as it does not have any function in this case.